# Having avg of sum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to combine avg of sum, but that gives me an error

```
select
count(orderId) order,
sum(amount) amountSum
from orders
group by productId
having sum(Amount > avg(sum(Amount))
```

I could close everything in

```
select * from (...) 
outer where outer.amountSum >
```

Here duplicate all query but calculate avg, is there a better way ?

Comment: Does sql server even accept double aggregate?Nevermind AVG(SUM doesnt make sense

Comment: It gives you an error? Perhaps you could share that error message? The query you posted has at least three syntax errors. You alias a column with a reserved word and didn't wrap it in []. The best fix there is use another alias. You don't have a comma between your columns and you are missing a closing parenthesis on SUM(Amount). Then you are trying to nest aggregates which doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Think closely about AVG(SUM(Amount))....the average is not going to change because you have an aggregate as the argument. The value of SUM(Amount) will never ever change per row. Maybe you are looking for SUM(Amount) > AVG(Amount). That would be syntactically and logically valid.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: `SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT ... ORDER BY SUM(amount)`

Comment: @SeanLange I just want to dispaly AmountSum grouped by product where AmountSum is bigger then avarange of all AmountSum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH order_stats AS ( 
    SELECT
        productId,
        order_count=COUNT(orderId),
        total=SUM(amount)
    FROM
        orders
    GROUP BY
        productId
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    order_stats
WHERE
    total>(SELECT AVG(total) FROM order_stats);
```

Comment: why is this ; needed at the beginning ?

Comment: @kosnkov Oh that's a habit... If you use the `WITH` clause, it is mandatory that the previous statement is terminated with a semicolon (`;`). Just to be sure I always start the `WITH` clause with a semicolon.